# Adding a content type to a list gives me a duplicate field error

Tags: development, powershell, content-type, column, duplicate

I have the following code:

```
list.ContentTypes.Add(contentType);
```

It works on my dev environment, but on test fails with the following error:

```
A duplicate field name "[GUID]" was found.
```

I've had several attempts at trying to find this field that it complains about via powershell (really simple script to get the web and then attempt to get the field by id) and it can't find it anywhere.

Can anybody please help me identify a possible cause for this duplicate field when I can't even find it?

Please note, I've tried this on different webs and the GUID is exactly the same, so it's a site column/field that exists and the site collection level I'm assuming (I've even ran the powershell script against the site's root web).

EDIT: I've also searched my solution for this guid - couldn't find it.

Comment: Let us see your content type defintion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the SharePoint Manager to find the duplicated field ID in the existing Site collection or on the relevent lists. Hopefully you will found it.

I wonder if it is possible for you to change the GUID of the field, causing the problem?

Update:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
$site = Get-SPSite "http://your.site.com"
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
{ 
    #iterates through all the Lists        
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $web.Lists.Count; $i++) 
    { 
      $list = $web.Lists[$i];                               
      $MyListContentTypes = $list.ContentTypes                                                          
      if ($MyListContentTypes -ne $null)
      {

         $cts = $list.ContentTypes
         foreach($ct in $cts)
         {
              if($ct)                                                            
              {


                $ct.FieldLinks.Delete($ct.Fields["GUID"])                                  
                $ct.Update()
             }   
         }                                  

       }
    }     
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT for your reply Falak. I can't appear to find the id in any of the content types?

Comment: Are you sure the field is not hidden? Can you paste the ContentTypes provisioning code?

Comment: Have you changed the GUID of the field causing the problem?

Comment: I can't change the GUID of the field because I don't know what field it is.

Comment: You need to iterate through all the webs and lists to find the required GUID. I have updated the script which could help you finding the field with specific GUID. Please run the script and provide me with more feedback.

Comment: Thanks so much Falak, really appreciate that. I'll run it now and let you know. EDIT: Just noticed it deletes the field - I'll probably adapt this to tell me what the field is for now so I can diagnose it further. Thanks again.

Comment: Great to know that :). Mark it as answer if it has helped you :)

Comment: Brilliant! I found out what field/s it was using your script. It hasn't solved my problem, but this thread was geared around diagnosing it - which your answer allowed me to do.

Comment: Thanks, your last comment has definitely made my day ;). Cheers and happy SharePoint stackexchanging :)